# How can I Publish A Blog Posts In The Future On A Specific Date And TIme In Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, scheduled-tasks, blogs

I'm at the beginner level using the laravel PHP framework. I worked on a blog web application, but I want to do some upgrade.

One of the upgrades is to be able to schedule posts to be published in the future on a selected date and time. Like that of Facebook, or that of rainlab blog in October CMS.

I don't know how to go about this, I would really appreciate it if someone can help me out.

Comment: By adding a datepicker in your admin panel that can set the date it should be visible?

Comment: @Jerodev thank you I will do that, but how will 
I go about the controller, and method?

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to implement delayed posting is to add publish date column (e.g published_at) to posts table and retrieve posts where publish date < now.

Schema:

```
$table->timestamp('published_at');
```

Retrieve example:

```
$posts = Post
    ::where('published_at', '<', now())
    ->orderByDesc('published_at')
    ->paginate(50);
```

Comment: Will I add the Retrieve example code in the PostController@index?

Answer (score 3):

1. The firstly i will create in database column like
       posted_at and show,that columns will be helpful later.
2. You should create command using

> php make:command MyCommand

3. Then in your app/console/command you will have your command
4. In app/console/kernel in

> protected variable $commands

register your command,put path

5. Inside your command using Eloquent or Db query get all posts where show=0 and posted_at

   ```
   $now=date("Y-m-d");
   $data=DB::table('test')->where('show',0)->whereRaw("posted_at<$now")->get();
   ```
6. Now you can use each loop and change show=1,something like that:

   ```
   $date->each(function ($item){
    DB::table('test')->where('id',$item->id)->update(['show'=>1]);
   });
   ```

Last job is put in kernel code which will be run after 1m,try this ->

```
$schedule->command('myCommand')->everyMinute();
```

EDIT:
So i checked my code i put changes so your command more or less should looks like this :

```php
 $now=date("Y-m-d");
 $data=DB::table('test')->where('show_',0)->whereRaw("date(posted_at)<='$now'")->get();
 $data->each(function ($item){
 DB::table('test')->where('id',$item->id)->update(['show_'=>1]);
```

Remember to put in header of your command this if you use DB

```php
 Use DB;
```

if Eloquent this but you must change the DB to Model_name

```php
use App\Name_model;
```

And that is Kernel.php

```php
protected $commands = [
        'App\Console\Commands\MyCommand',
    ];

// and 

protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
        $schedule->command('My:Command')->everyMinute();
    }
```

I check if after 1min records in my test database was change ,and show_=0 changed to show_=1 and that's all

Comment: please will that posted_at be a timestamp and that show be a boolean?

Comment: I have tried your code but it's not changing the show to true inside database

Comment: @IfeoluwaAdewunmi sure posted_at can be timestamp and show can be bool :),your scheduler working correct?[Schedule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/scheduling#introduction)

Comment: scheduler is not working. As you instructed in your answer above, I make a command, and I use your code in the Kernel but its not working.

Comment: @IfeoluwaAdewunmi check Edit

Comment: sorry I'm just seeing your edited answer, please for clarification, in which file will I add this set of codes?                          
 $now=date("Y-m-d");
 $data=DB::table('test')->where('show_',0)->whereRaw("date(posted_at)<='$now'")->get();
 $data->each(function ($item){
 DB::table('test')->where('id',$item->id)->update(['show_'=>1]);

Comment: Use ```php artisan make:command CommandName``` <- this will create a command and in this command put that code