# Publish created post on a certain date

Tags: php, laravel

Right now I have a working post create function that creates a post and sends a notification to the user that a post has been created. How do I manage this if the author of the post wants to publish the post at a certain date. Let's say they fill in a publish_date and i want the controller to create the post on that publish_date. Right now it just creates the post and send notification instantly.

```
public function create()
{
  $post = Post::create([
     'title'=>$request->title,
     'details'=>$request->details,
     'publish_date'=> $request->publish_date
  ]);    
  User::get()->each->notify(new PostCreated($post)); //sends notification to user using queue and redis
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I Publish A Blog Posts In The Future On A Specific Date And TIme In Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59155235/how-can-i-publish-a-blog-posts-in-the-future-on-a-specific-date-and-time-in-lara)

Comment: I think it answers only part of my question, the other part is how to deploy the notification? @AdamP.

Answer (score 0):

1. Alter your post table, add columns: *publish_date* and *status*. The first column will include the date (DATETIME) when you need to publish the post the second one - will include the status (ENUM or SMALLINT) of the post. You also can make this column like *boolean* in name it something like *is_published*. But my variant is more universal if you'll need to add more post statuses in the future.
2. Schedule command which will check the date in the post DB record, compare with the current date, and publish it.
3. Always wrap your create method with try/catch.
4. Remember about single responsibility. Your create method should contain only create functionality. If you want to send notifications, use Events and Event Listeners for this. If you'll bind notification sending with an event listener, you'll escape repeating code in the scheduled command from point 2 of this list. Your event listener will listen the save event and handle a job with notification sending